# Error when loading a template in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django-templates

I am attempting to have my template in a separate file and loading it with the Django loader.get_template('temaplte name'). Now this should work, however I get an error dealing with apps not being loaded. Any ideas on how to fix it? Also I am using python 3.2 in eclipse on windows.

source for loader:http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter09.html

```
from django.template import Template, Context, loader
from django.conf import settings

settings.configure()

t=loader.get_template('template.html')

c=Context({"Name":"Adrian"})
print(t.render(c))
```

Error message

```
  File "C:\Users\212412120\Downloads\Django-1.7\Django-
1.7\django\apps\registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Comment: Have you got any solution?? I am facing same problem.

Answer (score 0):

it's simply means check in your settings.py and within your installed_apps re-order how your apps are installed regarding their priorities.

Comment: Thank you, how can I fix the issue so i can load in a template from a separate file?